# how to give session value into string without type casting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want the value of session into string without type casting and conversion in ASP.NET.

But I want without any conversion get the value of Session["username"] into temp variable.
Example - the correct way is:

```
string temp;
Session["username"] = "Joy";
temp = Session["username"].ToString();
```

Comment: *Dear All,

 I know session is the object,But I want to know that can i take the value of session into string without any type casting OR conversion.
IT IS POSSIBLE OR NOT*

Answer (score 5):

Since Session is of type Object (so you can put in anything) you need to cast it back to String if you want to read it.

The preffered way of doing so is (since it may not exist in your session yet)

```
string temp = Session["username"] as String;
if (temp == null)
{
//Doesn't exist in Session yet, so create and add
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A session holds objects as values and therefore you need to cast the object into the correct type to gain the type's strength.
The session value can be null, so you need to check that.

```
string temp;
Session["username"]="Joy";
temp=Session["username"] as string;
```

if you use this:

```
object temp = Session["username"]; // temp is just a basic object.
```

Another issue is, since the session holds objects, value types are "boxed" into objects.
You can't use the "as" cast when you want to case value types, so:

```
int intTemp;
Session["num"]= 7; // int is boxed into an object
intTemp = (int)Session["num"]; // unboxed back to int
intTemp = Session["num"] as int; // cannot be done!!!
```

Comment: You could use "as int?" when using value types

Comment: It is true that casting object to int using the `as` keyword is not possible. However, you can still use `as` by casting it to `int?` (or  `Nullable<int>`) which will safely cast `null`, `int` or `int?`. Thus allowing null checking without first putting it into an object variable.

Comment: A nullable int isn't an int so why would you cast an int into a nullable? use the (<valueType>) cast for casting value type.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
temp=Session["username"] as string;
```

As session is an object it is necessary to type cat it to the prefered type..